# How to ignore specific echo when returning data to AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to get information from database using ajax call, and then get this information back to the ajax function with the data as JSON.
(I do this to change content in a specified time interval).

So in the PHP file I use `"echo"` with `"json_encode"` to return the SQL query data.

But there is also an echo from the `dbconfig.php` file, which is the file used to connect to the database. (It has  `echo "Connected Successfully";` in case the connection was successful)

Comment: why can't you just only echo when the connection fails? Also since you are using `json`, you can easily send a failed `json` response when the connection fails

Comment: Or don't echo at all in the `dbconfig.php`?

Comment: So you're suggesting not to echo at all when connection is successful?(only in case of failed connection)
Actually I'm a beginner and I probably copy the connection code from certain websites so I was sure it's not a bad thing to echo, but seems it does cause problems.

But is my general idea for sending data back OK?
i.e: AJAX call to PHP file > Getting data using SQL query > json_encode back to the AJAX function?

Thanks

Comment: If the response is expecting JSON, only return valid JSON.  If you have error messages, those could be put in a JSON response as well, in addition to setting the proper response code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method would obviously be to edit dbconfig.php to remove the echo statement. It isn't really useful; it's just included in tutorials/examples so you can see that something's happening.

If (for whatever reason) you're restricted from changing that file, you can include it in an output buffer to prevent that status message from being output with your JSON.

```
ob_start();
include 'dbconfig.php';
$connectionStatus = ob_get_clean();

// do your other stuff
```

Comment: Thank you, 
And may I ask something related to my original question:
Is the general idea of dynamically changing content correct?
as in my code: First make an AJAX call to a PHP script which gets data. From that PHP file echo back the data, and in the AJAX call upon success, you trigger a function that changes the content? Or you would do something else?
For example I want to change a div content to show different news headlines every 1 minute, and the headlines are stored in a "news" table in the database

Comment: That sounds like a pretty standard approach. Although you might want to load a set of headlines instead of just one and cycle through them for a bit before loading another set, to reduce the number of requests. As far as your general idea, though, it sounds fine.

Comment: Actually I tried with the single request with many interval and the web really slowed down. Your idea is obviously the correct! So I really only need to load once and loop through a regular JS / Jquery function instead :)! genius you are